# Can conversion function be virtual in C++?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, virtual

I am curious to know that is it possible to have conversion function that is virtual? If yes, it would be better if you explain it using an appropriate program. Is the call to conversion function will be resolved at runtime if it is virtual?

Comment: The only functions that can't be virtual are constructors (and technically allocation and deallocation function, but they're effectively virtual already). But it's usually not a good idea to make assignment or conversion virtual. Because it introduces dynamic (run time ) type checking.

Comment: @PravasiMeet _"Give the reason for downvotes"_ I didn't downvote, but most probably because your question shows no research efforts, nor a code sample that demonstrates any specific problem you actually have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This simple answer is yes, conversion functions can be virtual, so long as they are class methods.

Comment: This forum is primarily aligned at helping people debug existing code. If you have sample code that you are having difficulty with, please post it and ask a specific question about it.